# serviceSubscriberCellularProviderでcarrierNameが取得できません。

Tags: swift

subscriberCellularProviderがiOS12でdeprecatedになったので、
serviceSubscriberCellularProvidersに代えたのですが、
キャリアcarrierNameが取得できず困っています。

appleのドキュメントでは辞書型と書いてあるのでtest[“carrierName”]で取れると思うのですが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか。

```
if let test = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders{
  print(test)                //Ⅰ
  print(test[“carrierName”]) //Ⅱ
}
```

【debug window】

```
//print Ⅰ
["~~": CTCarrier (~~) {
    Carrier name: [ソフトバンク]
    Mobile Country Code: [440]
    Mobile Network Code:[20]
    ISO Country Code:[jp]
    Allows VOIP? [YES]
}
]

//print Ⅱ
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

**print I** の出力、当方の環境では、次のようになりました。

> ```
> ["0000000100000001": CTCarrier (0x2825fbe10) {
>     Carrier name: [ソフトバンク]
>     Mobile Country Code: [440]
>     Mobile Network Code:[20]
>     ISO Country Code:[jp]
>     Allows VOIP? [YES]
> }
> ]
> ```

特に秘密にしなければいけないような情報は見当たらないのに、なぜ`~~`のように情報を隠してしまうのでしょうか? この辺りAppleのドキュメントはイマイチの分野でもあり、この手の情報を正確にお示しいただいた方が、早く解決につながることが多いです。

そのAppleのドキュメント:

### [`serviceSubscriberCellularProviders`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/3024511-servicesubscribercellularprovide)

(抜粋)

> ```
> Each entry in the dictionary is a CTCarrier object,
> ```
>
> 辞書の各エントリーは`CTCarrier`オブジェクトです。
>
> ```
> the actual value of a key isn’t important,
> ```
>
> (辞書の)キーの実際の値は重要ではありません(訳注:「ですが…」と続きますが、今は無視)

つまりこの辞書の値は`"carrierName"`のようなキーで取れるとは一言も書いておらず、重要ではないキーに`CTCarrier`型の値がぶら下がっていると言うことです。

たとえばこんな風にしてみてください。

```
        if let providers = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders {
            if let provider = providers.first {
                print("key=\(provider.key)")
                let carrier: CTCarrier = provider.value
                print("Carrier name=\(carrier.carrierName ?? "?")")
            }
        }
```

[`CTCarrier`のドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier)を見れば、その他の情報をどうやれば取れるか、すぐにわかるかと思います。

Comment: CTCarrier型の理解が不十分でした。ご回答ありがとうございます。